# How to decide whether to use dimension column or fact measure in Power BI drill through page

Tags: powerbi, drillthrough

I have a page with table. Columns are:
Customer name, Sales count, Sales Amt

Another page with table. Columns are:
YearWeek, Sales count, Sales Amt

Another page I want to create for drill through. This has got table with YearWeek, Customer name, Sales count, Sames Amt. On This page what should I add to the drill through fields?

Can someone help me understand whether to add the dimemsion columns or fact measures as drill through fields?

I tried another example:

Page 1 is pie chart with Customer name and Sales Amt

Page 2 is table with Customer name and sales amt

On page 2 irrespective of whether I add Customer name or Sales Amt in the drill through field, the pie chart on Page 1 allows me to do the drill through.

So again my question is - how to decide whether to add the dimemsion column or fact measure as drill through fields?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to use drill-through as a means of transferring a filter context from a summary type page to a details type page. This means that most use-cases involve using columns as drill-trough filters and not measures.

However, if you have created a page that shows many different slicings of a certain measure, you could add this measure as the drill-through filter. Depending on your choice of "keep all filters", this will also apply any additional (columnar) filters corresponding to the filter context of the point from where you drilled through.

Comment: On summary page I have a pie chart with Customer name, Sales amt. On drill through page I can either add customer name or sale Amt. Both work. How do I decide which one to use.

Comment: That depends entirely on whether you want to drill through to this page from other summary pages or not. Then you would use whatever makes you able to drill through from both summary pages.

Comment: Can you explain me how to decide whether to place a dimension column or measure into drill through fields. I'm just unable to understand this clearly.

Comment: Apparently, I am not able to.